# String letter disappear

Tags: android

I am trying to write Sindhi language strings in TextView, but some letters disappear.
For e.g: when I write "ٿ", it is fine, but when i combine this another letter, as text.getText().toString()+"ي", so "ٿ", disappears and android is unable to combine these letters..
thanks for your help

Comment: on which version of android your trying

Comment: I am trying on 4.0.3... and today 4.1 is announced.. and string is shown properly on 4.1 Emulator..as "ٿيلو", but not shown properly on my tablet having os 4.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may helps you

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("ٿ");      
        String s1 = text.getText().toString();      
        String s2 =  s1 +" "+ "ي";      
        text.setText(s2.toString());
```

Comment: in textview any other property your set ?

Comment: explain your quetion in details and put your code Textview xml

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

this is my TextView,

Comment: i think you want to concate 2 string but using wrong method to set string

Comment: TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("ٿ");
        String s2 = text.getText().toString() + "ي";
        text.setText(s2);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16420/discussion-between-ankitmakwana-and-user1416561)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any library for displaying Sindhi Text. If not, use it else put it properly in assest folder.

Comment: I am simply doing text.setText("sindhi string"), it doesnt show some letters on screen.

Comment: Ya i know. But sometimes some font size are not available in devices, fr that you need to add it manually. As you are saying your text is display on 4.1 but not on 4.0. so will suggest you try to add that lib in your assest  folder then run it. Hope it will show you proper result.

Comment: Actually i am developing my own sindhi keyboard..so i cant not add all strings in Assets folder, or if i add..but android doesnot show these strings on screen..:(